# Bootstrap 4.1 - modal fails with 'Error: Object.keys: argument is not an Object'

Tags: bootstrap-4

Just updated our app from Bootstrap 4.0 to 4.1

Now Modals, that worked perfectly before, will not launch - e.g.

```
$('#PopupModalData').modal();
```

and fail in IE 11 (not been able to test with other browsers yet) with

```
Error: Object.keys: argument is not an Object
```

Any ideas what happened?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would appear that there is a bug (quite a major one if modals fail to open) in 4.1...

[Link to bug report at github](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/26327)

It will be fixed for 4.1.1, but no indication of when that will be released :-(

Comment: In the meantime I can confirm this is fixed in v 4.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

Try Bootstrap 4.1.2 patch https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap use

> dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
>
> dist/js/bootstrap.min.js

as a source files, its works fine for my application.